# Checkbox doesn't change its check-state when clicking on it

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, dom-events

I'm new in ASP.NET MVC and now I faced with a problem which occurs with checkbox if it appears on page later than page was originally loaded.
See the next scenario: when I click let's say a button, Javascript handler calls controller post-action, and its result html is loaded into some concrete div.
This html contains checkbox which doesn't react on mouse down event (**doesn't change its check-state**).

Checkbox works fine if it was rendered along with the whole page, but not if it was rendered later (as a result of post-action).
See my markup here:

```
<a name="button" onclick="handler();"></a>
```

On the "button" click I want to get `ActionResult` from a controller and put it into a div:

```
<div id="resultWillBeLoadedIn">
    <!-- here is placeholder-->
</div>
```

The next html will be returned from /SomeController/SomeAction and loaded into div above:

```
<span class="check">
    <span class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="form" value="2" />
    </span>
</span>
```

Here is a Javascript handler for my "button click":

```
function handler() {
    var url = '/SomeController/SomeAction';
    $.post(url, { params... }, function (result) {
        $('#resultWillBeLoadedIn').html(result);
}
```

See a part of CSS for it (I'm totally not an expert in CSS, so I'm not sure if that is that one I need to show here. And... (to be honest) I'm not an author of it, so please tell me if need more):

```
.check .checkbox{
float: left;
height: 12px;
width: 12px;
display: inline-block;
margin: 3px 5px 0 0;
cursor: pointer;
background: url(../img/checkbox.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.check span.disable{
float: left;
height: 12px;
width: 12px;
margin: 3px 5px 0 0;
display: inline-block;
background: url(../img/checkbox.png) 0 -24px no-repeat;
}
```

Please tell me what I'm missing to make checkbox working not only if it was rendered right on page loading, but not when it was rendered as a result of post back into some div.

Comment: Judging from the CSS, I guess you're using a trick to change the checkboxes' appearance. Maybe the actual checkbox is hidden by some other CSS code, and what you're seeing is the bg image.

Comment: Yes, it's how it is done.
But the thing confusing me - is that sometimes it works (when checkbox is rendered when page loaded), but sometimes - it doesn't (when checkbox loaded as dinamically into some div element).
I examined elements in both cases with the help of Chrome "Inspect Element" and found that in first case there are some jquery handlers  for both mouse-click and mouse-down events. And in the second case - only handler for mouse-click event, but not for mouse-down one.

Comment: There must be some other js code that runs on page load to initialize your custom checkboxes.

Comment: You're right! There really is .js file with the script which binds handlers for mousedown and takes care of background image for checkboxes.
The thing I've done to fix an issue was to use jquery .live() method to bind a handler. As I understand, in this case handler is bound to checkbox which is added to page even later.

Comment: Guys, I'm new at stackoverflow... What should I do to mark it as an answer? :)

Comment: I'll add an answer later so you can accept it ok? Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

You've omitted the handler for the checkbox, but you probably need to use a delegated handler for it (docs for [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)).  Essentially, you delegate the handler to a higher level element in the DOM that does remain on the page (or maybe the body element, if no lower level element will work) and supply a selector filter that is used when the handler is invoked to see if it matches the event target.  In this way you can have a handler that is applied once and works with dynamic elements that are added later.

```
$('body').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
      // handler function
});
```

Comment: I've updated a question and now you can see that I meant handler for a  "button" but not a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

After you add the html in the callback, then hook up a click handler.

```
$('selectCheckbox').on('click', handler);
```

Given the problem its likely a CSS/Styling issue. I think some element is floating over the checkbox and preventing it from being clicked on.  Can you look at it in chrome inspector and see what is getting hovered when you put your mouse over the checkbox?

Comment: Thanks, but this handler - is not a handler of a checkbox, but a handler of a "button" which posts an action which returns html with my checkbox (which actually doesn't work).
I will update a description to make it more clear...

Comment: You cant check and uncheck with the mouse or it doesnt fire something?  Clarify what the cb SHOULD do, not just what it doesnt

Comment: It should change its checked-state when clicking on it. But it doesn't do it.
It is not changed even visually.
Behaves like disabled, although it doesn't look like...